# CCC from one disk to external disk, then CCC back on Mac

Tags: macos, boot, ssd, external-hard-drive

Last year I used Carbon Copy Cloner to make a clone of my 2012 21.5 inch Mac running Mojave to an external drive. Sadly, it was NOT an SSD type drive. I upgraded the OS to Catalina on the new external drive to use Turbo Tax, which would no longer run under Mojave. People here were a big help.

I noticed that when booting off of the external drive, startup was MUCH faster.. After filing my taxes, the external drive died or at least could not be rebooted from. I was told if I wanted a bootable external drive to use an SSD type with no moving parts. So I did. It boots quickly.

My internal drive continues to take forever to boot up. In fact, it seems to be getting slower. So here is my question... would it make sense, now that I can boot off of the external drive to erase the internal drive and CCC from the external drive back to the internal drive. It seems like this would allow it to boot up faster from the internal drive.

Answer (score 0):

iMacs have notoriously slow drives, even the ones with Fusion drives.

If you don't want to consider having the internal upgrade to a new SSD, then continue to use the external as your boot drive.